# Can't access serialized data

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I must be missing something very simple here but I can't figure it out. I need to access serialized data which is stored in a database. 
In the database the stored value is

```
a:2:{s:8:"last_tab";s:1:"1";s:11:"footer_text";s:13:"Default Text2";}
```

I need to get the 'Default Text2'.

In my local environment i echoed

```
get_option( 'tt_options' )['footer_text']
```

and got the value I needed.

The problem arises in my staging environment. There, when I type

```
get_option( 'tt_options' )['footer_text']
```

the page crashes, although

```
get_option( 'tt_options' )
```

works fine.

The only difference I can think of between my local and my staging environment is that the tables in the database use different engines:

Staging environment: 
Engine: MyISAM

Local environment: 
Engine: InnoDB

By the way, I am using WordPress if that helps.

Anyway, I tried to access the value in several ways shown below. The lines that have been commented cause problem only in my staging environment. What i found interesting is that when i try to access the value from serialized data that is not stored in the database, but in a variable (see below:

```
echo ($returnValue['footer_text']);
```

), I get the value I need. Does anyone have any idea of what is causing the problem in order to point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance for your time and guidance.

```
$returnValue = unserialize('a:2:{s:8:"last_tab";s:1:"1";s:11:"footer_text";s:13:"Default Text2";}');

echo '0:: ';
print_r($returnValue);
echo "<hr>";

echo '1:: ';
echo ($returnValue['footer_text']);
echo "<hr>";

echo '2:: ';
//echo get_option( 'tt_options' )['footer_text'];
echo "<hr>";

echo '3:: ';
var_dump(get_option( 'tt_options' ));
echo "<hr>";

echo '4:: ';
//var_dump(get_option( 'tt_options' )['footer_text']);
echo "<hr>";  

echo '5:: ';
echo get_option( 'tt_options' );
echo "<hr>";

echo '6:: ';
print_r(get_option( 'tt_options' ));
echo "<hr>";

echo '7:: ';
foreach(get_option( 'tt_options' ) as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' : ';
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

The results I get from the previous code are shown below:

```
0:: Array ( [last_tab] => 1 [footer_text] => Default Text2 )
1:: Default Text2
2:: Default Text2
3::
array (size=2)
  'last_tab' => string '1' (length=1)
  'footer_text' => string 'Default Text2' (length=13)
4::
string 'Default Text2' (length=13)
5:: Array
6:: Array ( [last_tab] => 1 [footer_text] => Default Text2 )
7:: last_tab : 1
footer_text : Default Text2
```

**Revision 1:**

Yes @Kenney I am running different versions of php. Thank you for pointing it out. I didn't know what you just mentioned about the syntax in older versions of PHP.
The versions are:

local environment: 5.5.12

staging environment: 5.3.29

So, in my situation, if I can't control the php version which is installed, the only way to access the value is by using a foreach statement?

Regarding the collation and charset, I run the following query at the database

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE  `wp_options`
```

and got in both environments:

```
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I also checked my wp-config.php  files and what I found was:

staging environment:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

local environment:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

**Revision 2:**

Thanks a lot @Kenney ! That was helpful! Indeed there was a syntax error:

```
Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in footer.php on line 66
```

which was produced for the reason you previously stated.

To sum up for helping another person that might end up at this thread, using

```
echo get_option( 'tt_options' )['footer_text'];
```

with an older PHP version that 5.4.0 might not work, but

```
$temp = get_option( 'tt_options' );
echo $temp['footer_text'];
```

does.

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces
>   array() with [].

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: check the collations in your database tables and the encoding setting of your php db driver on both environments.

Comment: You're running different versions of PHP; not all of them support the syntax `somefunc()['somefield']`; use a temporary variable.

Comment: *"serialized data which is stored in a database"* ... now I has a sad :(

Comment: thought it was a good idea at the time

Comment: Serialized data is not always a bad idea, but it's a terrible idea if you ever need to search inside of it or manipulate properties quickly.

Comment: As per @Kenney, your production environment is running a version of php older than 5.4

Comment: Just to add my $0.02, I had some issues with serialized data not being saved correctly and what I did was to hex the data before saving it and then unhex it afterwards. My reason for saving serialised data in the first place was to locally cache about 30 drop-down menus in an included file in my application so that my script doesn't need to query the database each time. Maybe some people might think that approach is redundant, but in fact it's exactly the solution I needed - the drop-down menu options don't change very often though.

Comment: To clarify using a temporary variable: just do `$option = get_option( 'tt_options' ); echo $option['footer_text'];`. WP itself already calls `maybe_unserialize` which deserializes the option if it is serialized. As for the syntax not being supported: the page crashes because of a syntax error, there should be something in the logs about that, if nothing shows on the page.

Comment: Rather than editing your question to include an answer, please write up an answer and mark it as accepted. This will prevent the question from showing as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

As @miken32 mentioned, let me answer the question instead of editing it, in order to prevent the question from showing as unanswered.

The problem was the PHP version in my staging environment. It was lower than version 5.4.0, so it didn't support short array syntax.

To sum up for helping another person that might end up at this thread, using

```
echo get_option( 'tt_options' )['footer_text'];
```

with an older PHP version that 5.4.0 might not work, but

```
$temp = get_option( 'tt_options' );
echo $temp['footer_text'];
```

does. The trick is the use of a temporary variable before accessing the needed value.

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces
>   array() with [].

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php